# For-loop - Reduce the Nesting (n x m operations)

Tags: java, for-loop, refactoring

I try to make some code more readable (and thus maintainable). Let's start with the current iteration of the code:

```
int[] outerIterations = getDataToIterateOver();
for (int i : outerIterations) {
    for (int j : outerIterations) {
        if (i == j) continue;
        for (int a : getDataByIndex(i)) {
            for (int b : getDataByIndex(j)) {
                function1();
                function2();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It had some further nesting which I could already reduce, but I am still looking for how to write the code to have less nesting.

I am not a Java developer but doing C# and Golang, so I think I'm missing on some language feature that might help me here.

*Used Java version:* 17

Comment: `I think I'm missing on some language feature `. Well, that depends on the version of Java you are using. That could be helpful to know. Also, what is the looping supposed to do might be helpful, specially in the loops within `i == j`

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what this code snippet is actually doing because only enhanced for loops are being used, when indexing into the array would be more appropriate.  

Also, what's the purpose of the last 2 for loops if they don't use a or b in the functions?  If the code is correct, it seems like the main driver here is to just call those functions a specific number of times, which could be more clearly conveyed with a bit of math and a single for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I think I'm missing on some language feature

I guess it's not related to specific features of Java.

When you have a lot of actions creamed into a method, most likely you are dialing with a violation of the [*Single-responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

I understand that you've proved a simplified code-sample. Have a closer look at what your method is doing and which of these actions can be extracted out from it.

That's a dummy example on how to reduce the level of nesting.

```
public void doSomething() {
    int[] outerIterations = getDataToIterateOver();
    for (int i : outerIterations) {
        for (int j : outerIterations) {
            if (i == j) continue;

            doSomethingWithIJ(i, j);
        }
    }
}

public void doSomethingWithIJ(int i, int j) {
    for (int a : getDataByIndex(i)) {
        for (int b : getDataByIndex(j)) {
            function1();
            function2();
        }
    }
}
```

In case, if you assumed that this code could be made to be functional in style, i.e. to utilize Stream API instead, then you need to provide something close to the actual code. For now, it doesn't seems like you can apply functional programming here.

Comment: I do not think it is actually violating single responsibility principle. It is calculating a matrix of values. But extracting a method is probably an easy to go route.

Comment: @Sascha I do not insist that it's a clear case of violation, nesting is just an indicator. The more important point is that if it is possible to separate the phase of generating the input data from its processing, it's an easy way to make the method easier to read and to test.

Comment: @Sascha *It is calculating a matrix of values* - So `function1()` and `function2()` are responsible for updating a nested array like `int[][]`.  If it is not mandatory to change the state of an existing array, it might be possible to generate a new one using Java 8 streams. But it might not be simple.

Comment: even worse: `function1()` and `function2()` calculate stuff and write that off to a database in out use case.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer due to the approaches you provided and I think there is a too big variation in possibilities to answer that definitely as a future reference for everything (aka as a commonly agreed way of doing things)